# How to display external html in React Popup window

Tags: reactjs

In react I'm current using the library `reactjs-popup`

From a component I call a Popup window like so:

```
return(
  <>
  <form method="post" name="contactForm" class="contact-form" id="contact-form">
    { displayCustomFields() }
  </form>
  <PopupWindow
  custom = {custom}
  customFields = {customFields}
  />
  </>
)
```

In the popup component I have this:

```
return (
      <Popup
        arrow
        closeOnDocumentClick
        closeOnEscape
        modal
        mouseEnterDelay={100}
        mouseLeaveDelay={100}
        on={[
          'click'
        ]}
        onClose={() => {}}
        onOpen={function noRefCheck() {}}
        position="bottom center"
        repositionOnResize
        trigger={
          <div className="buttons relative">
            <span className="input-group-btn">
                <button className="btn-theme btn-detail" onClick={() => getPreviewTemplate()}>Preview</button>
            </span>
          </div>
        }
      >
        {I'd like to load some external html here}
      </Popup>
  );
```

As indicated in the Popup component I would like to load some html from an external page in the popup basically a complete html page.  How would I do this?  By external html I mean like "https.example.com/mypage.html"

Comment: as docs said you can add html there

Comment: Docs don't describe external html thou @NishargShah

Comment: what you mean by external html?

Comment: External html as in www.google.com any html page.  @NishargShah

Comment: so as iframe then

Comment: @Nisharg Shah Iframe only works with permission from the site.  "And I hope it’s clear that adding any URL into an Iframe doesn’t work with React or any other frontend library or framework unless the embedding site allows your web app domain to embed it."